# hadoop suggestions on how to process logs

Tags: java, regex, linux, apache-pig

I need some suggestions on how I should process infrastructure logs using hadoop in Java instead of Pig as I think Pig does not support regex filters while reading log files.

As an example, i have cisco logs and web server logs and I want to filter specific values by line and feed into hadoop.

There are couple of suggestions online i.e to first change it to csv format, but what if the log file is in GBs???

Is it possible to filter the lines at "map" stage i.e the program will read lines from the file in HDFS and send it to mapper...

I need some suggestions on best way and clean way to do this....

thanks.

Comment: You seem to be on linux, why not use `grep`, `sed`, ...?

Comment: i am aware of those, however the logs are pretty huge and i want to create some stats, i have already tried using pig to filter web servers logs by IP, but hit the limit with regex...so am hoping to do it in Java directly with hadoop.

Comment: So you think that java would be more efficient in comparison to `grep`?  Good luck.

Comment: yup...if i am talking about GB's of log

Comment: @krisdigitx, why would Java be faster than grep? With grep you are probably only limited by the disk read speed. In that case Java won't help you.

Comment: is not hadoop a faster way to process logs instead of grep???

Comment: @krisdigitx Hadoop is generally faster at processing things due to the inherent paralellism that the MapReduce algorithm provides. If however you are doing the filtering before you get to the map stage, I don't think there wll be much paralellism. The only way I can think of might be to make a custom input format, although that would only help if inputformats are run in paralell (which is not something I am sure of). If they do, that is your best bet if it absolutely must be done prior to the mapper. Personally however I recommend just moving the filter to the mapper.

Comment: You can use regex filters in Pig.

Comment: @DavisBroda, exactly what i am now doing...the input chunks are filtered in the mapper stage...i was able to process 2.7GB of logs in under 2min.

Comment: @krisdigitx: Please close the question if it got answered. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

We can do `REGEX` [operations](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html) on `PIG`. PIG internally uses [JAVA REGEX specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) only.

Please go through the following example:

```
myfile = LOAD '999999-99999-2007' AS (a:chararray);

filterfile = FILTER myfile BY a MATCHES '.*DAY+.*';

selectfile = FOREACH filterfile GENERATE a, SIZE(a) AS size;

STORE selectfile INTO '/home/jagadish/selectfile';
```

File used in the example is of size 2.7 GB contains 11 million lines. Out of which regex output is 450,000 lines.

I believe this answers your question, Otherwise please let me know.

Comment: i prefer to use the Java API instead of pig, as it as better regex filters and allows more control..